# Changing color of edge and face of polygon

Tags: geography, entity

How can I change color, `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm` of Georgia on the folowing map?

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black], 
Polygon[{Entity["Country", "Russia"], 
Entity["Country", "Georgia"]}]}, GeoBackground -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I tried:

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Green}], FaceForm[{Black, Green}], 
Polygon[{Entity["Country", "Russia"], 
Entity["Country", "Georgia"]}]}, GeoBackground -> None,PlotRange -> All]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `GeoGraphics[{
  EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Black],
  Polygon[Entity["Country", "Russia"]],
  EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Yellow],
  Polygon[Entity["Country", "Georgia"]]},
 GeoBackground -> None, PlotRange -> All]`